# Combinations for 4 letter word from the set {A,B,C,D} with at most one A, 2 B, 3C, and 4 Ds. No repetitions.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, generating-functions

Using synthetic multiplication of $(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$, I looked for the coefficient of $x^4$ and got 15.

This is the correct way to go about it by generating functions right?

Comment: Can you explain what represents every polynomial in the multiplication?

Comment: I could've first written $(1+A)(1+B+B^2)(1+C+C^2+C^3)...$ etc. but then I'd be easier to just use one common variable and look for the coefficients of $x^5$ which would mean the word is a 5 letter word instead of say AB^2CD as a variable.

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it.